# How to get last added element in array?

Tags: java, arrays

How can we get the **last added** element in array? I know how to do it with ArrayList, but in this case I have Integer array.

```
Integer[] result = new Integer[];
```

Comment: How do you add the element? Like this? result[5]=12345?

Comment: Maybe its a bit simple but , count the array and then the value it returns is the last added value in your array then -1

Comment: Also note that you need the size of the array upon initialization. `Integer[] result = new Integer[size];`

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks, that works!

Comment: Do you mean _last_ element in the array or "last added".

Comment: @Gray last added

Comment: if last added then why dont you use the variable that you use for indexing array

Comment: what if the "last added" is not added as last entry of a new array?

Comment: There is a way, but it won't work correctly if last added value might be null. Iterables.getLast(Arrays.stream(result).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()))